# Как закрыть все popover bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, popover

1. нажимаем первую картинку. Все ок.
2. Нажимаем вторую картинку. Все ок. первая закрылась.
3. Нажимаем первую картинку. вторая не закрылась.
   Почему?

   $(document).on("click", ".tab-image-detalize", function () {

   ```
   $(".tab-image-detalize").popover("hide");

   if ($(this).attr("data-isopen") === "true"){

       $(this).attr("data-isopen", "false");

       $(this).popover("hide");

       return;
   }
   $(".tab-image-detalize").attr("data-isopen", "false");

   $(this).attr("data-isopen", "true");

   $(this).popover("show");
   ```

   });

https://jsfiddle.net/5demsdL8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/5demsdL8/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".tab-image-detalize", function () {
        $(this).popover("show");
    });
    $('.tab-image-detalize').on("show.bs.popover", function () {
        $(".tab-image-detalize").not($(this)).each(function(){$(this).popover("hide");});
    });

});
```

Comment: При срабатывании события show.bs.popover выбираются все popover кроме текущего и сворачиваются. я правильно понял логику?

Comment: Да. Именно так.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь